# web service for POST method on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, post

Can i have a web service url to test the POST method on ajax call from my html page?. I need to write my datas to the service and retrieve whenever required. Have seen some available web services (ex. https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos), but they are giving me

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

error on POST method; while on GET method I'm able to fetch data from the service. So can anyone please help me to find a web service which can be used to write data to the service.

here is my code snippet.

```js
var obj = {
     id : id,
     name : name,
            last_name :last_name

          };

   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://httpbin.org",
             dataType: "json",
      data: obj,
             success: function (data) {
             alert(data.id);
             },
    
             failure: function (response) {
      alert(response);
             }

         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after an endpoint where you can test an HTTP POST. I would recommend giving http://httpbin.org/ a try.

I have used it quite a lot for my own testing and it can even be set up locally with ease (provided that you have Python installed). The main page has an index of the different operations that you can try, however it sounds like you are mainly after an HTTP POST which can be POSTed to: http://httpbin.org/post.

It's possible that your request might be failing due to missing credentials or an API token, as you are trying to create (POST) a repository on a user's behalf.

#### EDIT

Looking at the code snippet, you were so close :) httpbin does add additional HTTP data into the response as opposed to being a simple echo service, for example, what headers were used in the request amongst a few other items (which is pretty great for debugging). Give the following a go:

```
var obj = {
    id: 123,
    name: "Antony",
    last_name: "Hey!"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: obj,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: :). You might have something to point out with my code. Can you please have a look through my ajax request.

Comment: Sure, you were so close :)

Comment: Hi man. Now I'm able to upload data. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: But while trying to get the  http://httpbin.org/post , "Method Not Allowed.

The method is not allowed for the requested URL" is displayed on the window screen. So suggest me a way to have the data visible.

Comment: If you want to try a GET request try this: http://httpbin.org/get. That website exposes different URLs for different operations. That GET request should also work just by viewing it in the browser.